# $S=\{a,b,c,d\}$ is a finite sample space. Let $A=\{a,b,c\}, B=\{b,c\}$, and $C=\{c,d\}$. Assume $P(A)=0.8, P(B)=0.5$ and $P(C)=0.4$.

Tags: probability

$S=\{a,b,c,d\}$ is a finite sample space.

Let $A=\{a,b,c\}, B=\{b,c\}$, and $C=\{c,d\}$.

Assume $P(A)=0.8, P(B)=0.5$ and $P(C)=0.4$.

Find $P(\{a\}), P({a,d})$ and $P(C \text{ and } {\sim} B)?$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Note that $\{a\}\cup B=A$ and $\{a\}\cap B=\emptyset$. Therefore $P(\{a\})+P(B)=P(A)$, from where you can find $P(\{a\})$. From $A\cup\{d\}=S$ and $A\cap\{d\}=\emptyset$ you get that $1=P(S)=P(A)+P(\{d\})$. So you get $P(\{d\})$. Now $\{a,d\}=\{a\}+\{d\}$. So $P(\{a,d\})=P(\{a\})+P(\{d\})$. Since you already have $P(\{a\})$ and $P(\{d\})$, then you get $P(\{a,d\})$. Finally, the complement $B^c$ of $B$ is $\{a,d\}$. So, the event $C\text{ and} ~B$, which I write $C\cap B^c=\{d\}$. But you already computed $P(\{d\})$. So, you have it.

Comment: @drhab For P({a}): P(A)=08 so 0.8=P({a})+P({b})+P({c}) i am not sure how to go from there

Answer (score 0):

Denoting $p_a$ for the probability $P(\{a\})$ (and likewise for $b,c,d$) we have the equalities:

- $p_{a}+p_{b}+p_{c}+p_{d}=P\left(S\right)=1$
- $p_{a}+p_{b}+p_{c}=P\left(A\right)=0.8$
- $p_{b}+p_{c}=P\left(B\right)=0.5$
- $p_{c}+p_{d}=P\left(C\right)=0.4$

These equalities enable you to find $p_a,p_b,p_c,p_d$.

Further observe that

- $P(\{a\})=p_a$
- $P(\{a,d\})=p_a+p_d$
- $C\cap B^{\complement}=\{d\}$ so that $P(C\cap B^{\complement})=p_d$